# Concatenate Values from Different T-SQL Queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table in SQL Server with the following data:

```
+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
|Product Family   |  Product Class    |  Product          | Sales  |
|Food             |  Vegetables       |  Cauliflower      | 24     |
|Food             |  Prepared Meals   |  Steak & Patatoes | 54     |
|Food             |  Fruit            |  Apples           | 76     |
|Food             |  Fruit            |  Oranges          | 14     |
|Food             |  Fruit            |  Pears            | 32     |
|Electronics      |  MP3 Players      |  Cool Player Z    | 57     |
|Electronics      |  MP3 Players      |  iStuff 16GB      | 45     |
|Electronics      |  TV's             |  HD               | 96     |
|Electronics      |  TV's             |  Ultra HD         | 76     |
+-----------------+-------------------+-------------------+--------+
```

There is a hierarchy in this data:

1. Product Family
2. Product Class
3. Product

I'd like to create a query that will return the sum for each hierarchy level. This union does that:

```
SELECT 1 as Level,  [Product Family] as Item, SUM(SALES) as Sales 
FROM [dbo].[HK_Termp_01] GROUP BY [Product Family]

UNION ALL

SELECT 2 as Level, [Product Class] as Item, SUM(SALES) as Sales 
FROM [dbo].[HK_Termp_01] GROUP BY [Product Class]

UNION ALL

SELECT 3 as Level, Product as Item, SUM(SALES) as Sales 
FROM [dbo].[HK_Termp_01] GROUP BY Product
```

However, I also require an additional column that will be a concatenation of the 3 string columns, in the order of the hierarchy. The desired output being:

```
+--------------------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------+
| Level ||Item             |  Hierarchy                                    | Sales  |
| 1     ||Electronics      |  Electronics                                  | 274    |
| 1     ||Food             |  Food                                         | 200    |
| 2     ||Fruit            |  Food > Fruit                                 | 122    |
| 2     ||MP3 Players      |  Electronics > MP3 Players                    | 102    |
| 2     ||Prepared Meals   |  Food > Prepared Meals                        | 54     |
| 2     ||TV's             |  Electronics > TV's                           | 172    |
| 2     ||Vegetables       |  Food > Vegetables                            | 24     |
| 3     ||Apples           |  Food > Fruit > Apples                        | 76     |
| 3     ||Cauliflower      |  Food v Vegetables > Cauliflower              | 24     |
| 3     ||Cool Player Z    |  Electronics > MP3 Players > Cool Player Z    | 57     |
| 3     ||HD               |  Electronics > TV's > HD                      | 96     |
| 3     ||iStuff 16GB      |  Electronics v MP3 Players > iStuff 16GB      | 45     |
| 3     ||Oranges          |  Food > Fruit > Oranges                       | 14     |
| 3     ||Pears            |  Food > Fruit v Pears                         | 32     |
| 3     ||Steak & Patatoes |  Food v Prepared Meals > Steak & Patatoes     | 54     |
| 3     ||Ultra HD         |  Electronics > TV's > Ultra HD                | 76     |
+--------------------------+--------------+------+-------------------------+--------+
```

This is where I get stuck. I can't add all 3 fields to each query in the Union, because then I don't get the right totals by level. But I'm not sure what other avenue to try.

Thanks & Let me know what other info I can supply to clarify the case.

Comment: You can clarify the issue by showing what results you are trying to get.

Comment: Done, thanks Gordon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just want a tweak on your query:

```
SELECT 1 as Level,  [Product Family] as Item,
       SUM(SALES) as Sales 
FROM [dbo].[HK_Termp_01]
GROUP BY [Product Family]
UNION ALL
SELECT 2 as Level, [Product Family] + '>' + [Product Class] as Item,
       SUM(SALES) as Sales 
FROM [dbo].[HK_Termp_01]
GROUP BY [Product Family] + '>' + [Product Class]
UNION ALL
SELECT 3 as Level, [Product Family] + '>' + [Product Class]  + '>' + Product as Item,
       SUM(SALES) as Sales 
FROM [dbo].[HK_Termp_01]
GROUP BY [Product Family] + '>' + [Product Class]  + '>' + Product;
```

That said, you could do this using `GROUPING_SETS`:

```
SELECT [Product Family], [Product Class], Product, SUM(SALES) as Sales
FROM [dbo].[HK_Termp_01]
GROUP BY GROUPING SETS ( ([Product Family], [Product Class], Product),
                         ([Product Family], [Product Class]),
                         ([Product Family])
                       );
```

You would then need to fiddle with the names to get the exact output you want.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, this answer is brilliant. I was looking for the query tweak, but learning about GROUPING SETS was an added bonus!

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun,

```
Declare @YourTable table ([Product Family] varchar(50),[Product Class] varchar(50),Product varchar(50),Sales int)
Insert Into @YourTable values
('Food','Vegetables','Cauliflower',24),
('Food','Prepared Meals','Steak & Patatoes',54),
('Food','Fruit','Apples',76),
('Food','Fruit','Oranges',14),
('Food','Fruit','Pears',32),
('Electronics','MP3 Players','Cool Player Z',57),
('Electronics','MP3 Players','iStuff 16GB',45),
('Electronics','TV''s','HD',96),
('Electronics','TV''s','Ultra HD',76)

Declare @Top    varchar(25) = NULL       --<<  Sets top of Hier Try ''MP3 Players'' 
Declare @Nest   varchar(25) = '|-----'  --<<  Optional: Added for readability

;with cte0 as (
      Select Distinct ID=Product,Parent=[Product Class],Sales from @YourTable
      Union All
      Select Distinct ID=[Product Class],Parent=[Product Family],0 from @YourTable
      Union All
      Select Distinct ID=[Product Family],Parent='Total',0 from @YourTable 
      Union All
      Select Distinct ID='Total',Parent=NULL,0  )
     ,cteP as (
      Select Seq  = cast(100000+Row_Number() over (Order by ID) as varchar(500))
            ,ID
            ,Parent
            ,Lvl=1
            ,Sales = Sales
      From   cte0
      Where  IsNull(@Top,'X') = case when @Top is null then isnull(Parent,'X') else ID end
      Union  All
      Select Seq  = cast(concat(p.Seq,'.',100000+Row_Number() over (Order by r.ID)) as varchar(500))
            ,r.ID
            ,r.Parent
            ,p.Lvl+1
            ,r.Sales
      From   cte0 r
      Join   cteP p on r.Parent = p.ID)
     ,cteR1 as (Select *,R1=Row_Number() over (Order By Seq) From cteP)
     ,cteR2 as (Select A.Seq,A.ID,R2=Max(B.R1) From cteR1 A Join cteR1 B on (B.Seq like A.Seq+'%') Group By A.Seq,A.ID )
Select A.R1  
      ,B.R2
      ,A.ID
      ,A.Parent
      ,A.Lvl
      ,Title = Replicate(@Nest,A.Lvl-1) + A.ID
      ,Sales = (Select sum(Sales) from cteR1 S where S.R1 between A.R1 and B.R2)
 From cteR1 A
 Join cteR2 B on A.ID=B.ID
 Group By A.R1,B.R2,A.ID,A.Parent,A.Lvl
 Order By A.R1
```

Returns

[image]

Now, If you `set @Top = 'MP3 Players'` rather than NULL, you'll get :

[image]

**Just a little narrative:**

cte0, we normalize your hierarchy into a Parent/Child relationship

cteP, we build your hierarchy via a recursive cte

cteR1, we generate the sequence/R1 keys

cteR2, we generate the R2 Keys

Now, If yo have slow-moving hierarchies, I tend to store them with the range keys to facilitate navigation and aggregation.

Comment: Thanks John, not exactly what I needed, but very nice indeed,  I'm sure it will come in handy at some point.